# Why Don't Any of the Random Numbers Within an Array I Created in Js Not Repeating?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to understand why random numbers within the array `randomNumber` aren't repeating. I've executed the code 50x and the numbers never repeat within the array. **I'm actually very happy they are not repeating** but would like to understand why they're not repeating? Or is it a fluke they aren't repeating and I should soon see repeats?

```js
var numberOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var randomNumbers = [];


while (randomNumbers.length < 4) {
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOptions.length + 1);
  if (randomNumbers.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
  randomNumbers[randomNumbers.length] = randomnumber;
}

var html =
  "<p>My 1st number: " + randomNumbers[0] + "</p>" +
  "<p>My 2nd number: " + randomNumbers[1] + "</p>" +
  "<p>My 3rd number: " + randomNumbers[2] + "</p>" +
  "<p>My 4th number: " + randomNumbers[3] + "</p>";
document.querySelector("#number").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="number">
</div>
```

Comment: i have just tried it and it did repeat, it's just you for now. also there is no reason for them to not repeat

Comment: true to your last point. that's why i thought it was weird on my end that they never repeated. just a fluke on my end then it sounds like?

Comment: You are using a random number generator, why are you expecting it to repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code explicitly avoids duplicates:

```
while (randomNumbers.length < 4) { //until there are four random numbers, repeat:
  //generate a random number
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOptions.length + 1);
  //if the number is already in the array, go back to the beginning of the loop
  if (randomNumbers.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
  //if the number is new, add it to the array
  randomNumbers[randomNumbers.length] = randomnumber;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code basically says "if this number already exists in my random number array, repeat this loop and don't save it to my random number array."  It's quite literally preventing repeats!

```
if (randomNumbers.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
```